# ngx-infinite-scroll not working in mobile when is mat-sidenav layout

Tags: angular

I am developing Angular project by using mat-sidenav layout and routing. When used ngx-infinite-scroll for displaying a list of elements from a database. As I followed the user guide for ngx-infinite-scroll. But it is working fine in desktop. When I check in mobileview by using developer tools it is not working (sidenav dissappear). I have checked in emulators  also, but No use.

And I have tried with setting fixed height and [scrollWindow]="false" also but no use.

Can any one please help on this.

Thanks and Regards, Kumar.

Answer (score 0):

**StackBlitz example**
I have made an example for you: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-scroll-stack-001
In my opinion, your problem is the fact that you are binding the scroll to the actual window as ngx-virtual-scroll seems to be having issues with correctly detecting when the scroll is finished.

If you want to bind scroll to window, you might want to consider using custom directive instead as it's much simpler than watching inner scroll state of an element.

Another thing you could do is placing an IntersectionObserver at the bottom of the list and attaching a callback. Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

**Original answer**
Can you please provide us with an example of your setup and specifically which version of the ngx-infinite-scroll are you using? The question is too vague to be answered at this point.

Comment: Hi Kralovec,
  Thanks for the quick response.
  The version of Inifinite scroll is:  "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^8.0.1",
   my template code ::     <div infiniteScroll [infiniteScrollDistance]="1" [infiniteScrollThrottle]="50" [scrollWindow]="true"
      (scrolled)="onScrollDown()" (scrolledUp)="onScrollUp()">

Comment: That's quite odd, I managed to make it work with both scrollWindow to true and false. Check my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you so much Kralovec, I have tried above example also, but it is not working in mobile view with mat-side-nav container.  thank you so much.